# Turning a hover animation into an automatic animation with a 5 second delay

Tags: css, animation, transition

```
.flip-container:hover .back, .flip-container.hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.flip-container:hover .front, .flip-container.hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

/* END: Accommodating for IE */

.flip-container, .front, .back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 62px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.flipper {
  width:100%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front, .back {
  width:100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;

}
.front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  background-image: url(images/cleanblue.jpg);

}
.back {
  background-image: url(images/dark-black-nav.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);

}
.front .name {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

Currently this code works on hover but how do I change it to work on a delay without hovering?

Am very new to CSS so I know it has something to do with keyframes but not sure how to implement.

Comment: I'd bet money there's a tutorial or twenty on this exact sort of thing at quick grasp via a quick trip to your favorite search engine. I'd suggest giving it a quick shot, and come on back if you get stuck in your efforts.

Comment: yep did that and saw loads for the same hover however the ones that automate involve keyframes and that not something i am familiar with yet.